# Sum of Cosine Waves

Tags: trigonometry, wave-equation

Plot two waves on excel: $\cos(f_1)$ and $\cos(f_2)$ and their sum $[\cos(f_1) + \cos(f_2)]$.
The frequencies of the waves are $f_1= 2\pi*f$ and $f_2= 2 \pi*f*(1.1)$. Assume $f=1$

My question is how do we find the sum of 2 waves? and if there is a third wave $\cos(f_3)$ with $f_3= 2 \pi*f*(1.2)$. How do we find the sum of 3 waves?

Comment: Please format with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: There's not really much to do. The result of adding two cosines is a sum of two cosines, that's simple enough. But you *can* turn it into a product of two cosines if that seems simpler or more useful to you (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities). Also, I assume $f$ is your "time" parameter here - in that case, the frequency of the first is $1$ and second $1.1$ (the frequency is not the thing that changes, but the thing that multiplies it to set how fast it's oscillating).

Comment: For example if First wave cos(0) = 1 and the second wave cos(0) = 1 their sum is 2. But my professor showed me he still got the sum of them two waves is 1 so I’m confused

Comment: That's clearly not true, maybe he was mistaken, or you missed a 1/2, or he was discussing a product? But it's still unclear what's the frequency, and what's the "time" or whatever parameter you want. You state f=1, there are no variables left if you do that.

Comment: Presumably there’s an $x$ or a $t$ in there somewhere, otherwise you’re asking about the sum of two constants.

Comment: Actually in his excel he has the x column and then he wrote first wave : cos(2*pi*f*x) and second wave :cos(2*pi*f*1.1*x) and f =1

Comment: What you are saying here doesn't make sense. There is something your professor did that you did not follow and have not reproduced here. Unfortunately, what you have produced is not sufficient for us to be able to identify what is going on. You need to ask your professor about this. Please do so. I am sure that he will want to clear up this misunderstanding.

Comment: summing two sinusoidal waves (harmonics) with slightly different frequencies you get the [beats phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_%28acoustics%29)